# Mixed results running manage-bde from sql xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, xp-cmdshell, bitlocker

I'm working on improving some sql stored procedures and our server health monitoring processes that are mainly driven by sql today. One of them is checking the server hard drives bitlocker status.

I have a sproc that runs xp_cmdshell 'manage-bde -status' and looks for the auto unlock status for our external back up drive.

Running it through the stored procedure that runs as a SQLServiceAccount administrator account returns auto unlock enabled.

However running it through cmd line on any other local user account shows it disabled. Not finding much about this online, anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This isn't related to the SQL _language_,)

Comment: Sorry, we run SQL Server 2014/2016/2019. Same results on each server. Testing using SSMS.

Comment: Using SQL Server as a glorified system management tool is, well, problematic. For starters, troubleshooting and error reporting from T-SQL is... interesting, and running SQL Server under an administrator account is also a security risk (any bug or misconfiguration opens up a privilege escalation exploit for anyone with access to SQL Server). Parsing command line output must also come with many fun challenges. Though not a direct answer to the question, consider taking this small test case as an opportunity to move away from this setup and experiment with dedicated tooling.